# How to reference 'stand-alone', non-bundled version of SwiperJS

Tags: swiper.js

I'm working on a project which doesn't have a front-end build system - just HTML templates referencing ES6 modules for the necessary bits of JavaScript functionality. I'd like to integrate [SwiperJS](https://swiperjs.com/). I can see on the [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#use-swiper-from-cdn) there's a link to the CSS and JS files served via a CDN but they reference the full bundled version, which is quite large in file size. I only need the core functionality and the navigation and pagination plug-ins, nothing else, but I'm struggling to find out how to reference these independently in this kind of project (as opposed to a fully frameworked-up Vue/React kind of project). I've tried downloading all of the assets into a separate project and copying them into my working project, in the location in which I'd like them (`/scripts/vendor/swiperjs/`) but when I try to load the module in my HTML page like this:

```
<script type="module">
  import Swiper from '/scripts/vendor/swiper/swiper.esm.js'
</script>
```

…it gives an error in the browser console related to the directory paths not being right (it's running via a local web server):

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "ssr-window". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

It feels wrong to be having to trawl through the swiper files and change all of the directory paths, so I must be doing something wrong. It may be that I've missed something and this whole approach won't work without something like Webpack.

Can someone please advise how to reference just the core swiperjs module and navigation and pagination plug-ins in this kind of project please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elsewhere in the documentation it deals with this: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#using-build-script. It's a case of downloading the repository and creating a custom bundle. Then, instead of referencing `swiper.esm.js` you need to reference `swiper-bundle.esm.browser.min.js` as that version seems to be the one that will run independently in the browser.

Comment: I had to add `.js` for success:
`import Swiper from './node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.esm.browser.js';`